# Cannot access different object inside another in Javascript, it gives ReferenceError: abc is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, scope

The below code has two scope of objects, where the first one has a function and the second one has another function. Both the functions gets called separately at the time of page loading. But Cross object method cannot be called.

I cannot understand how to make a function available to the scope of another object.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function ($, W, D) {
        var abc = {};
        abc.UTIL = {
            setMsg: function (r, d) {
                // code
            },
        };
        $(D).ready(function ($) {
            abc.UTIL.setMsg();
        });
    })(jQuery, window, document);

    (function ($, W, D) {
        var efg = {};
        efg.UTIL = {
            setNote: function (r, d) {
                // code
            },
        };
        $(D).ready(function ($) {
            efg.UTIL.setNote();
            abc.UTIL.setMsg(); // gives error message - ReferenceError: abc is not defined
        });
    })(jQuery, window, document);
</script>
```

In the above code segment I get this error "ReferenceError: abc is not defined"
How to solve this issue?

Comment: Put `var abc` outside of the IIFE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
 var abc;
 (function ($, W, D) {
    abc = {};
```

---

Because `var abc;` defined in the first IIFE, it is not available out of its scope, So the solution is to define it outside and update/assign the object/methods in the first IIFE and then you can access in the second IIFE.

---

or you might like to use namespacing like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = app || {}; // <-------declare an object here.
    (function ($, W, D) {
        var app.abc = {}; //<------assign it here.
        app.abc.UTIL = { // <--------access/assign method this way.
            setMsg: function (r, d) {
                // code
            },
        };
        $(D).ready(function ($) {
            app.abc.UTIL.setMsg();// <--------call it this way.
        });
    })(jQuery, window, document);

    (function ($, W, D) {
        var app.efg = {};//<------assign it here.
        app.efg.UTIL = { // <--------access/assign method this way.
            setNote: function (r, d) {
                // code
            },
        };
        $(D).ready(function ($) {
            app.efg.UTIL.setNote();
            app.abc.UTIL.setMsg(); // <----now it would be available.
        });
    })(jQuery, window, document);
</script>
```

This would let you put all your code in a namespace and restricts to polluting the global namespace.

Answer (score 2):

`abc` is defined within a function. To be able to access it everywhere, you need to define it out of the function scope.

So :

```
var abc = {};
(function ($, W, D) {
```

Answer (score 2):

`abc` is the local variable of the first `IIFE`. Take it out of all the functions to make it **Global**.

```
var abc = {};

(function($, W, D) {
    abc.UTIL = {
        setMsg: function(r, d) {
            // code
        },
    };
    ....
})(jQuery, window, document);

(function($, W, D) {
    ....
    $(D).ready(function($) {
        efg.UTIL.setNote();
        abc.UTIL.setMsg(); // gives error message - ReferenceError: abc is not defined
    });
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

**OR**

Make it **Global** by adding to `window`:

```
(function($, W, D) {
    window.abc = {};
    window.abc.UTIL = {
        setMsg: function(r, d) {
            // code
        },
    };
    ....
})(jQuery, window, document);

(function($, W, D) {
    ....
    $(D).ready(function($) {
        efg.UTIL.setNote();
        window.abc.UTIL.setMsg(); // gives error message - ReferenceError: abc is not defined
    });
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

**OR**

```
var abc = (function($, W, D) {
// ^^^^^^^^
    var abc = {};
    abc.UTIL = {
        setMsg: function(r, d) {
            // code
        },
    };
    ....


    return abc;
    // ^^^^^^^^
})(jQuery, window, document);

(function($, W, D) {
    ....
    $(D).ready(function($) {
        efg.UTIL.setNote();
        window.abc.UTIL.setMsg(); // gives error message - ReferenceError: abc is not defined
    });
})(jQuery, window, document);
```